# J Query Full Bg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm using the JQuery plugin to make an image full screen. I'm using some css to make the image fit the screen but when I click to exit full screen and then click to go back to full screen it seems to ignore the css that I set. Some of this code is code that I inherited when taking over a project so there is some of it that I don't fully understand.

```
 .fullBg {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                overflow: auto;
                z-index: 1;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;                
            }
```

This is the JQuery code;

```
( function($) {
    $.fn.fullBG = function(){
        var el = $(this);

        el.addClass( 'fullBg' );

        function resizeImg() {
            var imgwidth = el.width(),
                imgheight = el.height(),
                winwidth = $(window).width(),
                winheight = $(window).height(),
                heightdiff = winwidth / imgwidth * imgheight,
                new_width = ( heightdiff > winheight ) ? winwidth : winheight / imgheight * imgwidth,
                new_height = ( heightdiff > winheight ) ? winwidth / imgwidth * imgheight : winheight;

            el.css( { 'width' : new_width + 'px', 'height' : new_height + 'px', 'visibility' : 'visible' } );
        }

        $(window).resize( function() {
            resizeImg();
        } ).resize();
    };
} )(jQuery)
```

When I click on the fullscreen it sends me back to the original image, this code seems to handle this. I noticed there is a remove class "fullbackground" piece of code, is this causing my problem?

```
<img id='fullbackground' height="480px" width="640px" alt="" onclick="ExitfullBackgroundImage()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        var IsFull = false;
        var IsShowed = false;
        var isShowedAbout = false;
        function ShowIcon() {
            if (!IsFull) {
                var p = $("#fullbackground");
                var position = p.position();
                $("#divIcon").css("left", (position.left + 600) + "px");
                $("#divIcon").css("top", (position.top + 440) + "px");
                $("#divIcon").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#divIcon").hide();
            }
        }
        function HideIcon() {
            $("#divIcon").hide();
        }
        function fullBackgroundImage() {
            IsFull = true;
            $("#fullbackground").fullBg();
        }
        function ExitfullBackgroundImage() {
            if (IsFull) {
                $("#fullbackground").width(640);
                $("#fullbackground").height(480);
                $("#fullbackground").removeClass("fullBg");
                IsFull = false;
            }
            else if (!IsFull) {
                IsFull = true;
                $("#fullbackground").fullBg();
            }
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styling from the CSS is appended to the class `fullBg`, and that classname is removed when the image is clicked. What you can do is add the class in the else statement, so when the image is clicked again the classname is set:

```
function ExitfullBackgroundImage() {
    if (IsFull) {
        $("#fullbackground").width(640);
        $("#fullbackground").height(480);
        $("#fullbackground").removeClass("fullBg");
        IsFull = false;
    }
    else if (!IsFull) {
        IsFull = true;
        $("#fullbackground").attr("style","");  // <-- clear the inline styles set by javascript
        $("#fullbackground").addClass("fullBg"); // <-- add class
        $("#fullbackground").fullBg();
    }
}
```

However, I would consider improving this code a bit by making more use of css:

CSS:

```
#fullbackground {
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
}
#fullbackground.fullBg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;                
}
```

Javascript:

```
function ExitfullBackgroundImage() {
    $("#fullbackground").toggleClass("fullBg"); 
    // toggleclass 'toggles' the classname on/off

    if($("#fullbackground").hasClass("fullBg")){ 
        $("#fullbackground").fullBg();
    } else {
        $("#fullbackground").attr("style","");
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that was the problem, thanks I'll give that a go

Comment: @Ronan I've updated my answer, but note that when you remove the classname, the fullBg still remains active, so when you resize the window, it will still resize the image. You may also need to remove this event handler. It would be nice if the plugin offered a `disable` or `off` functionality

Comment: This line of code $("#fullbackground").attr("style",""); has done the trick, thanks a lot for that

Answer (score 0):

When I should guess (I wasn't able to run it yet) you might have a problem with case-insensitivity. The method is spelled "fullBG()" but you're calling ".fullBg();" on that. Since Javascript is case-sensitive, you might need to call ".fullBG();" with capital G. The method adds the class 'fullBg' to the background etc.

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it is still removing the CSS class when I click out and then click back onto fullscreen